# Start and shutdown tomcat via ssh

Tags: ssh, tomcat

**Updated**

I find out that the path of jdk it using is wrong. `eval: 1: /opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java: not found` the `Java` should be lower case `java`, how is that happen? When I run this script directly on server, it is just okay.

---

I'm trying to start or shutdown tomcat via a remote client.

On my server, I've got 3 different tomcat: tomcat1, tomcat2, and tomcat3.

Firstly, I've tried to run `tomcat_path/bin/shutdown.sh` to stop it via ssh, and the command is

`ssh jake@1xx.3x.2x.1xx  "cd /home/jake/tomcat2/bin;exec bash ./shutdown.sh"`

both `"` and `'` are tried, but do not work, the output is

`eval: 1: /opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java: not found`

it seems that the shell script runs on my local client, because on server it has this file.

Is there any way to run a shell script on remote server correctly?

**updated**

I've run

`ssh jake@1xx.xx.25.100  "sh -x /home/jake/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh > /home/jake/tomcat.log 2>&1"`

and the output in tomcat.log is :

```
+ PRG=/home/jake/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
+ [ -h /home/jake/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ]
+ dirname /home/jake/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
+ PRGDIR=/home/jake/tomcat/bin
+ EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh
+ [ ! -x /home/jake/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh ]
+ exec /home/jake/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop

eval: 1: /opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java: not found
```

Comment: You should just be able to run `... /home/jake/tomcat2/bin/shutdown.sh` - what happens if you try that ?

Comment: Still the same output `eval: 1: /opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java: not found`

Comment: `... sh -x /home/jake/tomcat2/bin/shutdown.sh > /home/jake/tomcat.log 2>&1` and post the log file here.

Comment: @quanta still the same problem here

Comment: Could you check to execute via ssh jake@your.ip.add.here "/opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java -version ? Is there an setenv.sh within your tomcat directory (to define the java path)?

Answer (score 2):

> I find out that the path of jdk it using is wrong. eval: 1:
>   `/opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java`: not found the Java should be lower
>   case java, how is that happen? When I run this script directly on
>   server, it is just okay.

Because you've set the wrong environment variables somewhere (may be `~/.bashrc`). bash reads the different startup files based on the different shell types. Keep in mind that:

- `ssh user@host 'command'` is a non-interactive shell
- whereas `ssh user@host` and run the command is an interactive shell.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: I've tried `ssh jake@125.39.25.100 ./home/jake/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` but that runs the script on client, not the remote server.

Comment: Remove the dot before `/home...`.

Comment: still the same problem. I think it is because the error shows `eval: 1: /opt/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/java` the path should be `java` but here is `Java`

Comment: `grep '/opt/Java' ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile /etc/profile...`?

Comment: in `/etc/profile` there is `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_25`, and the `java` is lower case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an odd env variable not being set. For fun ... try to find any instance of "/opt/Java" ... an 'easy' way to do that is

```
find /etc -type f |grep -v ' ' | xargs grep /opt/Java
```

That may point to a bad config file on your system.

There could also be an odd (very odd) chance ... that you have a weird ssh config which allows client env variables to be passed (and set) on the server. [Rare situation ... but is theoretically possible]